# Knight's Tour random move picker not working

Tags: java, knights-tour

I am working on randomizing which move my knight takes in my knight's tour code. For some reason though, my switch statement always goes to default, instead of executing a possible move. I know my possible moves methods work because I have separately ran `firstMoveChoice()` on it's own and it worked. So I know the problem is with my random move picker, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for your help and time in advance! It is really much appreciated as I have looked this problem over and cannot find the answer.

```
public class MoveKnight extends Moves {

public int[][] moveTheKnight() {

    Moves switchBetweenMoves = new Moves();
    switchBetweenMoves.startingLocation();

    while (knight != 64) {
        int randomMove = new Random().nextInt();
        switch (randomMove) {
            case 1:
                switchBetweenMoves.firstMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 2:
                switchBetweenMoves.secondMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 3:
                switchBetweenMoves.thirdMoveChoice();
                break;

            // other possible moves

            default:
                System.out.println("No more possible moves.");
                break;
        }
        break;
    }
    return board;
}
}
```

Here is the result of the above code:

```
1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
No more possible moves.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is my Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MoveKnight myKnight = new MoveKnight();
    myKnight.moveTheKnight();
}
```

Here is my ChessBoard class:

```
public class ChessBoard {

int[][] board;

public ChessBoard() {
    this.board = new int[8][8];
}
}
```

Here is `firstMoveChoice()`

```
public int[][] firstMoveChoice() {

System.out.println();

x += 1;
y += 2;

if (x >= board.length) { // this tests to make sure the knight does not move off the row
    System.out.println("Cannot move off board on x axis\n");
    x -= 1;
    y -= 2;
    return board;
}
else if (y >= board.length) { // this tests to make sure the knight does not move off the column
    System.out.println("Cannot move off board on y axis\n");
    x -= 1;
    y -= 2;
    return board;
}
else if (board[x][y] != 0) { // this prevents the knight from landing on a previously landed on square
    x -= 1;
    y -= 2;
    System.out.println("Cannot move onto a used square\n");
    return board;
}
else { // this moves the knight when the above statements are false
    board[x][y] = ++knight;
    System.out.println("This executed and the knight moved\n");

    for(int[] row : board) {
        printRow(row);
    }

    if (knight == 64) {
        System.out.println("Knight has completed the tour");
        }

        return board;
    }
}
```

Here is `thirdMoveChoice()`: It is practically the same as all the others, except for the change in numbers for the different moves.

```
public int[][] thirdMoveChoice() {

System.out.println();

x += 2;
y -= 1;

if (x >= board.length) { // this tests to make sure the knight does not move off the row
    System.out.println("Cannot move off board on x axis\n");
    x -= 2;
    y += 1;
    return board;
}
else if (y >= board.length) { // this tests to make sure the knight does not move off the column
    System.out.println("Cannot move off board on y axis\n");
    x -= 2;
    y += 1;
    return board;
}
else if (board[x][y] != 0) { // this prevents the knight from landing on a previously landed on square
    x -= 2;
    y += 1;
    System.out.println("Cannot move onto a used square\n");
    return board;
}
else { // this moves the knight when the above statements are false
    board[x][y] = ++knight;
    System.out.println("This executed and the knight moved\n");
}

for(int[] row : board) {
    printRow(row);
}

if (knight == 64) {
    System.out.println("Knight has completed the tour");
    return board;
}

return board;
}
```

Comment: You should check the range of possible integer values returned by `nextInt()`... Also it's not wise to create a new instance of `Random` everytime you want to create a new random integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `random.nextInt()` return a value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647

you should use the `random.nextInt(int n)` that return a value between 0 inclusive and n exclusive

so replace

```
int randomMove = new Random().nextInt(); b
```

by

```
int randomMove = 1 + new Random().nextInt(3);
```

Also, you should assign `new Random()` to a field that would be reused.

Comment: I have a problem now. When it executes `case 3:` which would move it 2 squares down and 1 square to the left (moving it off the board), my if... else statements in my above code don't handle it and it gives me an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Since I don't have the implementation of  `thirdMoveChoice() `, it' going to be complicated.

Comment: Now, how come it is not running in an infinite loop? obviously if it can't get to 64 with only the moves I provided,but it should at least try to move around the board. Instead everytime I run it, it randomizes a move, and terminates.

Comment: This is because of the `break;` at the end of you while loop.

Comment: I took out the break and it now works partially. It got to the right side of the board and tried to move off, but it couldn't so it tried another move and went somewhere else and that worked. However, when I ran it again it tried to move off right away, and _that_ gave me the same `outOfBoundsException -1`

Comment: I just added the thirdMove code to my original post. Please forgive my redundant code. :)