# Switch statement isn't going to default

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have been working on an implementation of the knight's tour problem, and have come across a small problem in my code.

The problem I have is with my switch statement. I am confused as to why after it goes through all the possible moves, and no more of them work, it doesn't go to default like I want it too. Instead it prints out the final board but keeps right on running doing nothing so that I have to cancel the build.

Any help will be appreciated!

My goal is to get it to display "No more possible moves." instead of running on forever when it can't move anywhere else.

Here is an example of the output: It stops at 53 in the bottom left corner.

```
1  0  41  34  3  38  23  36  
42  33  2  39  44  35  46  21  
7  40  43  4  19  22  37  24  
32  11  6  0  26  45  20  47  
0  8  0  18  5  16  25  0  
10  31  12  51  14  27  48  0  
53  0  9  30  17  50  15  28  
0  0  52  13  0  29  0  49  
BUILD STOPPED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Here is my switch code:

```
public class MoveKnight extends Moves {

public int[][] moveTheKnight() {

    Moves switchBetweenMoves = new Moves();
    switchBetweenMoves.startingLocation();

    while (knight != 64) {
        int randomMove = 1 + new Random().nextInt(8);
        switch (randomMove) {
            case 1:
                switchBetweenMoves.firstMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 2:
                switchBetweenMoves.secondMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 3:
                switchBetweenMoves.thirdMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 4:
                switchBetweenMoves.forthMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 5:
                switchBetweenMoves.fifthMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 6:
                switchBetweenMoves.sixthMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 7:
                switchBetweenMoves.seventhMoveChoice();
                break;

            case 8:
                switchBetweenMoves.eighthMoveChoice();
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("No more possible moves.");
                break;
        }
    }
    return board;
}
}
```

Comment: it will go to default when `randomMove` is not between `1` and `8` inclusive.  I don't see anything in your code that prevents that from being the case

Comment: Question is still unclear to me---whether do you want to get your `default` in switch statement to run? If the question is so,then it is not possible...

Comment: Instead of [repeatedly asking these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26762449/knights-tour-random-move-picker-not-working), check out the official tutorial on [control flow statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) as well as the documentation for [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). See also [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/616460) for more information about what you should do before posting here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I did not mean to be rude and ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default case will never be executed because of `int randomMove = 1 + new Random().nextInt(8);`...

Here,the output of `new Random().nextInt(8)` will always be from 0 to 7 as 8 is exclusive and so `1+new Random().nextInt(8)` will always vary from 1 to 8!

Default case is executed only if the parameter to be matched doesn't match any of the cases,in that situation it'll pass to default. But,you have explicitly mentioned cases for 1 to 8---hence,`default` won't come into picture!

> The nextInt(int n) method is used to get a pseudorandom, uniformly
>   distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value
>   (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

Answer (score 0):

`Random.nextInt(8)` produces values in the range 0-7, because the parameter is *exclusive*.

Your code, which adds 1 to that, can never produce a number greater than 8.

Everything is behaving as expected.

Comment: Ok, so I still need a way to break out of my switch statement and while statement when it gets to `default.`?

Comment: @ChristopherSpencer-It won't ever run default how many times you run unless you change the code!

Comment: Don't have a default - there is no need. All you'll lose is the println.

Answer (score 0):

Random.nextInt(int n): Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value **(exclusive)**, drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

Your `randomMove` variable varies between 1 and 8. `default` case will only execute when `randomMove < 1` or `randomMove > 8` which is never.

Suggestion to change your while conditional to, if I understand your code properly:

```
while (knight != 64 && switchBetweenMoves.hasValidMoves())
```

where hasValidMoves returns true if and only if valid moves exist, which are all moves in range of the knight which have not already been visited.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, It looks like the `default` case in your switch statement is **not** the correct place to check for completion.

Instead, I'd focus on the condition in your while statement.  Currently, it's the following:

```
while (knight != 64) {
```

You can also use `break` statement to break out of your while loop

if I were to guess, the value of `knight` is how many squares it's been on, going by that, This is how I might structure your `while` loop

```
while(knight < 64)
{
    if(/*you have no more moves*/)
    {
        System.out.println("No more possible moves.");
        break;
    }

    //logic for moving
}
```

---

Your code will only go to the `default` case, when `randomMove` does not match any of the cases.

However, the way you define `randomMove`

```
int randomMove = 1 + new Random().nextInt(8);
```

That will never be the case

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: How would I implement the `/*you have no more moves*/` part? I was wanting to do something like this, but I couldn't figure out how.